# mod_rewrite doesn't always work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to use `mod_rewrite` on an Apache server where I can't access `httpd.conf`, so I use this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php
```

It should redirect `http:` to `https:` and append ".php" if no file extension is present. Example:

```
     http://my.web.server.de/helloworld/m/contact    ––>
    https://my.web.server.de/helloworld/m/contact.php
```

The `https:` redirect works, but when I omit the ".php" file extension, I receive a 404 error. No error is written to the log.

I thought maybe SSL is the issue, so I removed the HTTPS part:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But it still doesn't work, the file ending isn't appended. I am consfused. Why doesn't it work?

The server is Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu).

Comment: Your last set of rules works for me. Is there anything else in your .htaccess that might interfere?

Comment: No, I removed everything else to try it out

Comment: This might be difficult to troubleshoot without access to .conf files. What happens if you remove both conditions and add `[R]` flag to RewriteRule?